# How to compile the com.android.sdk package?

Tags: android, android-source

I am working on windows with JDK, Android SDK and eclipse set successfully. I download the com.android.sdk package from:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Stk

But when I import the project to the eclipse, errors happen everywhere. Mostly is about the com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.stk.something cannot be imported. I googled to find the reason. It only says because of the these packages is internal package and cannot import with standard SDK. So the question is:
How can I compile this project?
Should I make a linux environment and get the whole android source code to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relaying on internal packages is not a good idea. They can be changed anytime by platform developers and your app can stop working. Also they do not guarantee same behavior on different Android platform versions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if I want to develop something about STK function. The only way is to use JNI to call the low level library. It's much difficult for me. Is there any good way to do this?